# Why my folder storage from file manager unisharp when i push to gitlab?

Tags: php, laravel

Is it fine when i push my laravel project to gitlab that have unisharp file manager, storage folder from unisharp is not uploaded to gitlab?

Here's in my local laravel project

[image]

Here's my gitlab

[image]

Comment: check .gitignore file once.might be ignored folder so

Comment: Yes, there is folder storage from file manager in file .gitignore.. what i have to do?

Comment: you need to remove that folder name if you want to upload

Comment: Alright, thankyou for your help!

Comment: Please don't just keep the question hanging. If the posted answer helped/contains the solution, you should accept it. If it didn't help and you solved it some other way, you can post your own answer and accept that. If the answer didn't help and you haven't solved it, please update us with the status.

Answer (score 0):

It Look Like storage folder name added in .gitingore file.So those files and folder which specified in .gitignore file wont be tracked

Official Documentation

> gitignore - Specifies intentionally untracked files to ignore.
>
> A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git
> should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected;

Ref:https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore